# Convert float to string with at least one decimal place (javascript)

Tags: javascript

Let me give you an example.

```
var a = 2.0;
var stringA = "" + a;
```

I will get: `stringA = "2"`, but I want: `stringA = "2.0"`.

I don't want to lose precision however, so if:

```
var b = 2.412;
var stringB = "" + b;
```

I want to get the standard: `stringB = "2.412"`.

That's why `toFixed()` won't work here. Is there any other way to do it, than to explicitly check for whole numbers like this?:

```
if (a % 1 === 0)
    return "" + a + ".0";
else
    return "" + a;
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to append `.0` to output from a Number to String conversion and keep precision for non-integers, just test for an integer and treat it specially.

```
function toNumberString(num) { 
  if (Number.isInteger(num)) { 
    return num + ".0"
  } else {
    return num.toString(); 
  }
}

Input  Output
3      "3.0"
3.4567 "3.4567"
```

Comment: This is definitely way cleaner than what I suggested :) Thank you

Comment: I actually don't know if `isInteger()` or modulo is "cleaner", but both work - bottom line is with floating point values you have to treat integer as a special case somewhere

Comment: For those who like one-liners: ``const toNumberString = n => `${n}${Number.isInteger(n) ? ".0" : ""}` ``

Answer (score 32):

There is a built-in function for this.

```
var a = 2;
var b = a.toFixed(1);
```

This rounds the number to one decimal place, and displays it with that one decimal place, even if it's zero.

Comment: Downvoted because the requirement clearly stated that precision was not to be lost when a decimal place existed. toFixed(1) forces it to one decimal place.

Comment: Still super helpful, though, so I'm not gonna downvote

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/753632/johann, what do you think happens if you do a.toFixed(3)?

Answer (score 4):

For other people looking at this question, it just occurred to me, that to convert a float to a string with at least `n` decimal places, one could write:

```
function toAtLeastNDecimalPlaces(num, n) {
    normal_conv = num.toString();
    fixed_conv = num.toFixed(n);
    return (fixed_conv.length > normal_conv.length ? fixed_conv : normal_conv);
}
```

Note that according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed, `toFixed()` will work for at most 20 decimal places. Therefore the function above will not work for `n > 20`.

Also, the function above does not have any special treatment for scientific notation (But neither do any other answers in this thread).

Answer (score 3):

If a is your float do

```
 var a = 2.0;
    var b = (a % 1 == 0) ? a + ".0" : a.toString();
```

Edited: add reference and change to allow for .0
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp

Comment: This won't solve the problem. If a = 2.0, my string will be "2", not "2.0".

Comment: Actually, I proposed the same in question (using modulo to check for integer)

Comment: Yeah I went back for your answer and made it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

This solution tries to balance terseness and readability

```
const floatString = (n) => Number.isInteger(n) ? n.toFixed(1) : n.toString();
```